# output vhdl signal assignment

Tags: output, signals, vhdl, assign

I have this signal assignment for a case in the output. Can any one help me understand what it means?

```
comb_master_command:
    master_command_o <= '1' when  voltage_converted > V0VOLT and  voltage_converted <= V2VOLT else
                      '0';
```

So I understand '1' is assigned to master_command_o if `voltage_converted > V0VOLT`   ...

but what does the `and`  mean here?? and the next part `voltage_converted <= V2VOLT` is `V2VOLT` assigned to `voltage_converted` or is it a condition of voltage less then or equal to `V2VOLT`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your snippet is a conditional signal assignment. The condition that it's subject to must evaluate to TRUE to assign a '1'. The expression comprising the condition is the logical AND of  both `voltage_convert > V0VOLT` and `voltage_converted <= V2VOLT` which are relational comparisons returning BOOLEAN values. When those conditions aren't met a '0' is assigned. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.3 Conditional signal assignment statements and 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements.  A condition is syntactically distintc and requires no parentheses here.

Comment: voltage_converted > V0VOLT 'and'  voltage_converted <= V2VOLT;

 else so the AND here is logical operator AND? is that you mean?

Comment: That's what I wrote. AND is found in 9.2.2 Logical operators.

Comment: OK, Understood. I am new to VHDL,so request you to kindly bare with me please, Thank you.

Comment: [‘Bare’ or ‘bear’?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/bare-or-bear). Perhaps you meant '..kindly bear with me please...'?

Comment: xDDD bear* I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read this line as:

```
master_command_o <= '1' when (voltage_converted > V0VOLT and voltage_converted <= V2VOLT)
                    else '0';
```

The `and` means that you need both conditions: `voltage_converted > V0VOLT` and `voltage_converted <= V2VOLT` to be valid. Meaning that `voltage_converted` is within the range: `] V0VOLT, V2VOLT ]` will result `master_command_o` to be `'1'` else `'0'`

Comment: will result in '1'? you mean?

Comment: If I am really pedantic it should be `( V0VOLT, V2VOLT ]` as the lower range is exclusive and the upper range inclusive.